# Human Height Estimation using walking stride

Tags: computer-vision

Are there any papers or research showing a correlation between walking stride and human height? My purpose is to estimate height from walking stride of a person.

Answer (score 3):

I did not find scientific data, but interesting ratio is mentioned on several sports sites like [this](https://www.walkingwithattitude.com/articles/features/how-to-measure-stride-or-step-length-for-your-pedometer):

Women have ratio 0.413 and men 0.415 and it is used by multiplying height with ratio and we get the stride length.

```
My lenght 182cm, 
ratio 0.415
stride length 182 x 0.415 = 75.53cm
```

Comment: Quite intrigued by the difference in the heights..

Comment: Thanks, this was quite useful. Did you by any chance find the reason behind this ratio?